# Untrusted Host "localhost" in

Tags: 8

From Drupal 8 beta 6 (released today), I have this error :

> Error message UnexpectedValueException: Untrusted Host "localhost" in
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request->getHost() (line 1221 of
>   core/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php).

I use this local url to call my site: http://theming.dev

Inside my setting file, I have:

```
     $settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
        'theming\.dev$',
     );
```

Note, this error is displayed only when I uncomment this lines:

```
 if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/settings.local.php')) {
   include __DIR__ . '/settings.local.php';
 }
```

What is the problem please ? Thanks.

Comment: Does settings.local.php exist?

Comment: Yes, I have here /sites/default/settings.local.php

Comment: And you've update `$settings['trusted_host_patterns']` in that file too?

Comment: `$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^localhost$',
  '^localhost\.*',
  '\.local$',
);`
is now `$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^theming$',
  '^theming\.*',
  '\.local$',
);`

Comment: Can you not specify the IP address of your server, or use a domain name?

Comment: @AxelBriche, do you still have a problem with this base on your updated settings you posted as a comment?

Answer (score 28):

This problem occurred for me when building an 8.0.0-beta6 test site on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop.  I have an Apache web server running locally, with the test site defined using a `VirtualHost` directive.  I add the domain name of the test site ("example.com") to my `/etc/hosts` file, pointing to 127.0.2.1, to bypass the need to use real DNS entries.

After installing the site, everything looked fine.  However, I noticed a warning message on the Status Report page about not having `trusted_host_patterns` set, so I went into my `/sites/default/settings.php` file and added these lines:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^example\.com$',
  '^www\.example\.com$',
);
```

Upon saving the file and reloading my browser, I got a very generic error page and, after commenting-out the new lines, noticed the `Untrusted Host "localhost"...` log message.

It appears that because I'm web-browsing from the same computer on which the web server is running, the Host is at some point getting converted to `localhost`, and thus is failing to match the set of patterns I had specified.  I was able to fix this issue by changing these lines to:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^example\.com$',
  '^www\.example\.com$',
  '^localhost$',
);
```

On a site that is intended to be put into production, you might want to utilize a `settings.local.php` file to specify `^localhost$` as a valid host pattern for testing purposes only.  Note that if you want to do this, you'll need to uncomment these lines in the default `settings.php`, and move them to the bottom of the `settings.php` file:

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/settings.local.php')) {
  include __DIR__ . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

In this case, the `settings.php` file would only contain the actual domain names:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^example\.com$',
  '^www\.example\.com$',
);
```

and `settings.local.php` would contain:

```
<?php
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'][] = '^localhost$';
```

to append `localhost` to the list of valid hosts.  With this configuration, you would not copy the `settings.local.php` file when copying the site to the production server.

Comment: Did you gave this problem on all pages on your site, or just some?

Comment: Like @hampercm I had to have ^localhost$ on the end of my array like: 'code' $settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array( '^alpha8\.local$', '^localhost$',); 'code'

Comment: @MPD: Yes, I had error messages for all pages on my site before the fix I posted above, though it also seemed to depend on the web browser:  Chrome on Ubuntu would only display the error when in Incognito mode.  Chrome on Android displayed the error always.  Firefox on Ubuntu doesn't display the error.

Comment: Scratch "Chrome on Android" off the list of browsers I gave in my previous comment.  That was a different issue that I ran into on the same day :)