# How do I configure the trusted host settings?

Tags: 8, configuration

I have changed the Trusted Host Settings on my website where I currently installed Drupal beta 8.0 alpha version. But in the error report it is still saying that
"Trusted Host Settings NOT ENABLED" . I have changed the code as follows.

```
// Before
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^www \ .example \ .com$',
);
```

```
// After
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^www \ .technicalreply \ .com$',
);
```

The error report is still saying that trusted host settings are not enable. What did I do wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: What are the spaces in the regex, are they a copy/paste error?

Comment: These are just copy paste error I have created myself here as editor does not allow code to publish here.ignore them

Comment: Maybe look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145690/untrusted-host-localhost-in and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145286/what-does-the-provided-host-name-is-not-valid-for-this-server-mean